# I keep getting a cryptic error from Unity 3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is the error:

`Assets/Scripts/TriggerCode.cs(6,43): error CS1513: } expected`

This is the section of code that Unity is detecting

```
void triggerCollide (Collider other) {    
        public string ObjectCollided = other;
        if (OnTriggerEnter.ObjectCollided == "Player" || "Sphere") {
            SceneManager.LoadScene("YouWon");
        } 
        else if (OnTriggerEnter.ObjectCollided != "Player" || "Sphere") {
            OnTriggerEnter();
        }
    }
```

Mainly the line `void triggerCollide (Collider other) {`

I don't get what it wants me to do.

Comment: Field definitions such as `public string ObjectCollided = other;` can't be placed inside of method definitions.

Comment: Also, the `||` operator does not do what you seem to think it does, judging by the way you are using it. `if (OnTriggerEnter.ObjectCollided == "Player" || "Sphere")` is not valid,  but maybe `if (ObjectCollided == "Player" || ObjectCollided == "Sphere")` would be more of what you expect.  Also, you probably mean to do `string ObjectCollided = other.name;` instead of `public string ObjectCollided = other;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what this script is attached to but if it's on the player, and it has a collider, you just need this:

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
{
    if (col.name == "Sphere")
        SceneManager.LoadScene("YouWon");

    // Do something else here if it's not an object named "Sphere"
}
```

Also, you can't declare a variable that has an accessor (public, private, etc...) inside a function.